# What happens if i overwrite the callback of the pytorch-lighting multiple times?

Tags: python, pytorch-lightning

I observed that the method **on_train_batch_end()** exists in the Class: **pythorch_lightning.callbacks.Callback**, meanwhile, this method also exists in **pytorch_lightning.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint**. What happens if I write two classes to inherit the above two classes and rewrite this method?

Will they work at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the [official repo](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/blob/accd2b9e61063ba3c683764043030545ed87c71f/src/lightning/pytorch/trainer/trainer.py#L1183) specifically between line `1183` to `1194`

```py
callbacks = self.callbacks
if monitoring_callbacks is True:
    # the list of "monitoring callbacks" is hard-coded to these two. we could add an API to define this
    callbacks = [cb for cb in callbacks if isinstance(cb, (EarlyStopping, Checkpoint))]
elif monitoring_callbacks is False:
    callbacks = [cb for cb in callbacks if not isinstance(cb, (EarlyStopping, Checkpoint))]

for callback in callbacks:
    fn = getattr(callback, hook_name)
    if callable(fn):
        with self.profiler.profile(f"[Callback]{callback.state_key}.{hook_name}"):
            fn(self, self.lightning_module, *args, **kwargs)
```

The callback hook is called in order of `self.callbacks`. If `enable_checkpointing=True`, and `ModelCheckpoint` is not in `callbacks` array, it will append default `ModelCheckpoint` (see [this](https://github.com/Lightning-AI/lightning/blob/accd2b9e61063ba3c683764043030545ed87c71f/src/lightning/pytorch/trainer/connectors/callback_connector.py#L122))

```py
def _configure_checkpoint_callbacks(self, enable_checkpointing: bool) -> None:
    if self.trainer.checkpoint_callbacks:
        if not enable_checkpointing:
            raise MisconfigurationException(
                "Trainer was configured with `enable_checkpointing=False`"
                " but found `ModelCheckpoint` in callbacks list."
            )
    elif enable_checkpointing:
        self.trainer.callbacks.append(ModelCheckpoint())
```

So to answer your question, no it doesn't run both at the same time, but they run sequentially

Comment: Can I define the execution order of these callbacks myself?

Comment: I think so, it just a list of callbacks after all

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But I still want to know how to define this order?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzqjvW8-bKk)?